# Can I invoke Linux terminal from javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal

I know javascript(client side script) is restricted to use system resource!

Any how can I invoke Linux terminal from javascript? It is OK to ask confirmation from the user before executing the shell.

Anyone has solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but I'd have to say this won't be possible. JS is very limited in how it can interact with the OS and is usually limited to the browser.

Comment: No, JavaScript can't really do this.

Comment: No, you can't: JS is restricted to the _browser_, not the client's OS... if it wasn't we'd all be in a world of trouble

Comment: Definitely not, executing system commands from a browser would be a huge security hole

Comment: If you are fine going with IE **only** - ActiveX (might be, not an expert at all of this). Other browsers do not allow it at any circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big No.

The only way would be to make an ajax call to the server that will do the linux calls for you.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a Linux terminal from a browser is quite impossible.

There is however a Javascript based PC emulator which does run Linux

http://bellard.org/jslinux/